# Mongodb $lte $gte date filter return one day later

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, filter

I'm working on a project that have a datepicker filter that works well locally (Brazil), but when I run it on production were server is at North America my query result return documents that have the date field one day later.

```
query.updatedAt = {
      $gte: new Date(moment(ctx.query.startDate).startOf('day')),
      $lte: new Date(moment(ctx.query.endDate).endOf('day'))
};


//this is what I got when logging 'query.updateAt'. The expected result
{ 
    '$gte': 2019-01-15T02:00:00.000Z,
    '$lte': 2019-01-16T01:59:59.999Z 
}
```

For some reason when at production, this same query returns documents were 'updateAt' field have values 2019-01-17

Comment: Add the timezone offset to date.

Comment: set default timezone using https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/